# Navigating back to previous page takes me back to login page in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a calendar page in a flutter app that when I click the "Add Event" button it takes me to another page where I can enter event data and save it to the db.

In the onPress: event of the RoundedButton on the Add Event screen, I use this code to go back to the previous page, the calendar page:

```
RoundedButton(
                  title: 'Save Event',
                  colour: Colors.blueAccent,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = true;
                    });
                    try {
                      ref
                          .read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                          .updatenewEvent(true);
                      if (currentEventId != null && currentEventId != '') {
                        ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier).saveEvent(
                            ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider), currentEventId);
                      } else {
                        ref
                            .read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier)
                            .updateEventDescription(
                                eventDescriptionController.text);

                        ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider.notifier).saveEvent(
                            ref.read(eventsNotifierProvider),
                            eventDescriptionController
                                .text); // Create new event
                      }
                      Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Go back to previous page

                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = false;
                      });
                    } catch (e) {
                      // todo: add better error handling
                      print(e);
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

The problem is that when it pops the page, I am taken back to the login screen.

I am using a bottom bar navigator to navigate to other screens after I log into the app. I am sure this has to do with the widget tree and the navigation bar.

How do I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed('/calendar');
```

try to use this code, this might help you.